# LibGDX: Rectangles aren't colliding / overlapping correctly?

Tags: java, libgdx, collision, rectangles

**Player Class**

```
public class Player extends Sprite implements InputProcessor {
    public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();
    private float speed = 500;
    public Rectangle rectangle;
    public Player(Sprite sprite){
        super(sprite);
        this.rectangle = sprite.getBoundingRectangle();
    }
    public void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch){
        update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        super.draw(spriteBatch);
    }
    public void update(float delta) {
        rectangle = new Rectangle(getX() + velocity.x * delta,0,rectangle.getWidth(),rectangle.getWidth());
        setX(getX() + velocity.x * delta);
    }
}
```

**PlayScreen Class**

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {
    private Player player;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
    private TiledMap map;
    private Rectangle rightRectangle, leftRectangle, playerRectangle;
    //private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        renderer.render();
        renderer.getSpriteBatch().begin();
        player.draw(renderer.getSpriteBatch());
        renderer.getSpriteBatch().end();

        //shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
        //shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
        //shapeRenderer.rect(
        //  player.getX() + player.velocity.x * delta, 0, 
        //  player.rectangle.getWidth(), player.rectangle.getHeight());
        //shapeRenderer.end();
    }
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        camera.viewportWidth = width;
        camera.viewportHeight = height;
        camera.update();
    }
    @Override
    public void show() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        map = new TiledMap();
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
        //shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

        player = new Player(new Sprite(new Texture("img/player.png")));
        rightRectangle = new Rectangle(1280,0,0,720);
        leftRectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,0,720);

        boolean wallLeft = leftRectangle.overlaps(player.rectangle);
        boolean wallRight = rightRectangle.overlaps(player.rectangle);

        if(wallLeft){
            System.out.println("wallLeft Overlap");
            player.velocity.x = 0;
        }
        else if(wallRight){
            System.out.println("wallRight Overlap");
            player.velocity.x = 0;
        }
        player.setPosition(
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2f - player.getWidth()/2f,
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2f - player.getHeight()/2f 
                - Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5f);
    }
}
```

Doesn't seem to be colliding correctly. The `rightRectangle` and `leftRectangle` are my screen side bounds. When I use the `shapeRenderer`, it produces the `ShapeRendered` rectangle and it will follow my player around. However, I believe that my `player.rectangle` is not moving at all for some reason, resulting in it not colliding with my side bounds. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*If the widths of the leftRectangle and rightRectangle weren't 0 (ie. 1 or 0.0001), after I open up the application, it will automatically print out "wallLeft Overlap" once and the player will still be able to move freely. When it is 0, nothing prints out and player is still able to move freely. So I don't think the widths of the leftRectangle and rightRectangle is the problem.

Comment: Did you tried to use shaperenderer for every rectangle that you want to check your collision?

Comment: Yes, I just added the leftRectangle and rightRectangle bounds onto shapeRenderer and it seems like it should work correctly, but it's not colliding. I can provide a picture if that may help?

Comment: Your `leftRectangle` and `rightRectangle` have no width, they can't overlap anything. That said, you only do the overlap check in the show method, which will get called exactly one time when the screen is shown.